# Wrong output when parsing with lxml python

Tags: python, parsing, xml-parsing, lxml

I am parsing a big xml file. Below is a snippet containing two cell-line objects. When I am parsing the xml file with lxml I am receiving wrong results. For example lxml returns back `synonyms` only for the first object, and assigns NaN to the `cell-name` which is nor correct.

```
<Cellosaurus>
<header>
<terminology-name>Cellosaurus</terminology-name>
<description>Cellosaurus: a controlled vocabulary of cell lines</description>
<release version="35.0" updated="2020-07-02" nb-cell-lines="123199" nb-publications="19758"/>
<terminology-list>
 <terminology name="DrugBank" source="Wishart's group" description="DrugBank database">
  <url>https://www.drugbank.ca/</url>
 </terminology>
</terminology-list>
</header>
<cell-line-list>
<cell-line category="Transformed cell line" created="2012-10-22" last_updated="2019-05-24" 
entry_version="12" sex="Female" age="Age unspecified">
<accession-list>
  <accession type="primary">CVCL_E548</accession>
</accession-list>
<name-list>
  <name type="identifier">#15310-LN</name>
  <name type="synonym">15310-LN</name>
  <name type="synonym">Extract 519</name>
</name-list>
<comment-list>
  <comment category="Transformant">
    <cv-term terminology="NCBI-Taxonomy" accession="10376">Epstein-Barr virus (EBV)</cv-term>
  </comment>
  <comment category="Part of"> 12th International Histocompatibility Workshop (12IHW) cell line panel 
</comment>
</comment-list>
<species-list>
  <cv-term terminology="NCBI-Taxonomy" accession="9606">Homo sapiens</cv-term>
</species-list>
<web-page-list>
  <url><![CDATA[http://bioinformatics.hsanmartino.it/ecbr/cl326.html]]></url>
  <url><![CDATA[http://pathology.ucla.edu/workfiles/360cx.pdf]]></url>
</web-page-list>
<xref-list>
  <xref database="dbMHC" category="Cell line databases/resources" accession="48439">
    <url><![CDATA[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/gv/mhc/xslcgi.fcgi?cmd=subj&ID=48439]]></url>
  </xref>
  <xref database="ECACC" category="Cell line collections" accession="94050311">
    <url><![CDATA[https://www.phe- 
     culturecollections.org.uk/products/celllines/generalcell/detail.jsp? 
     refId=94050311&collection=ecacc_gc]]></url>
  </xref>
</xref-list>
</cell-line>
<cell-line category="Hybridoma" created="2017-08-22" last_updated="2018-09-07" entry_version="2">
<accession-list>
  <accession type="primary">CVCL_KA96</accession>
</accession-list>
<name-list>
  <name type="identifier">#16-15</name>
  <name type="synonym">Ter 479</name>
  <name type="synonym">Extract 519</name>
</name-list>
<comment-list>
  <comment category="Monoclonal antibody target">
    <xref-list>
      <xref database="UniProtKB" category="Sequence databases" accession="Q5T5X7">
        <property-list>
          <property name="gene/protein designation" value="Human BEND3"/>
        </property-list>
        <url><![CDATA[https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q5T5X7]]></url>
      </xref>
    </xref-list>
  </comment>
  <comment category="Monoclonal antibody isotype"> IgM </comment>
</comment-list>
<species-list>
  <cv-term terminology="NCBI-Taxonomy" accession="10090">Mus musculus</cv-term>
  <cv-term terminology="NCBI-Taxonomy" accession="10116">Rattus norvegicus</cv-term>
</species-list>
<derived-from>
  <cv-term terminology="Cellosaurus" accession="CVCL_4032">P3X63Ag8.653</cv-term>
</derived-from>
<reference-list>
  <reference resource-internal-ref="PubMed=25400923"/>
</reference-list>
<xref-list>
  <xref database="RCB" category="Cell line collections" accession="RCB4635">
    <url><![CDATA[http://cellbank.brc.riken.jp/cell_bank/CellInfo/?cellNo=RCB4635&lang=En]]></url>
  </xref>
  <xref database="Wikidata" category="Other" accession="Q54422067">
    <url><![CDATA[https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q54422067]]></url>
  </xref>
</xref-list>
</cell-line>
</cell-line-list>
</Cellosaurus>


doc = etree.parse('test-cells.xml')
results = []

for att in doc.xpath('//cell-line'):
    key_values = {}
    try:
        key_values['cvcl'] = ''.join(att.xpath('.//accession[@type="primary"]/text()'))
        key_values['sex'] = att.attrib['sex']
        key_values['age'] = att.attrib['age']
        key_values['synonym'] = att.xpath('.//name[@type="synonym"]/text()')
        key_values['cell_name'] = att.xpath('.//name[@type="identifier"]/text()')
    
    except:
        key_values['sex'] = None
        key_values['age'] = None
        key_values['category'] = None
        key_values['synonym'] = None

    
    results.append(key_values)

df_cols = ['cvcl', 'synonym', 'cell_name', 'sex']
out_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = df_cols)    
out_df.head()
```

Output:

```
        cvcl    synonym cell_name   sex category
0   CVCL_E548   [15310-LN, Extract 519] [#15310-LN] Female  Transformed cell line
1   CVCL_KA96   None    NaN None    None
```

This is wrong as the second cell-line is missing `synonym` and `category`. Which does not make sense. I appreciate any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or what I am not understanding here

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but probably will be better off structuring your code this way:

```
results = []
expressions = ['.//accession[@type="primary"]/text()','.//name[@type="synonym"]/text()',
               './/name[@type="identifier"]/text()','@sex','@category']
for att in doc.xpath('//cell-line'):
    result = []
    for expression in expressions:
        target = att.xpath(f'{expression}')
        if len(target)>1:
            result.append(target)
        if len(target)==1:
            result.append(target[0])
        if len(target)==0:
            result.append('none')
    results.append(result)
df_cols = ['cvcl', 'synonym', 'cell_name', 'sex','category']
out_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = df_cols) 
out_df
```

Output:

```
       cvcl     synonym                   cell_name     sex     category
0   CVCL_E548   [15310-LN, Extract 519]   #15310-LN    Female   Transformed cell line
1   CVCL_KA96   [Ter 479, Extract 519]    #16-15       none     Hybridoma
```